# Retrieve physical host information from virtual machine vmware, such as MAC-address

Tags: asp.net, virtual-machine, vmware, host, vmware-player

I am working on a project that includes licensing. When the license server is installed on a physical machine I can easily retrieve the host information about the computer through WMI.

The problem is when the license server is installed on a virtual machine, the host information that is returned by WMI is about the virtual machine. I don't want that. I want to compare the hardware information only to the physical machine.

**My question is. How to I retrieve information about the physical machine when on the virtual machine? Such as the MAC-address, BIOS ID etc...**

I have the virtual machine installed on the VMware, and it is not installed on the Hyper -V, so I can't reach information from the HKLM/SOFTWARE/../Parameters, but that information is insufficient anyways.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
public static string returnMACAddress()
    {
        string mac = string.Empty;
        foreach (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface nic in System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                mac = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return mac;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Mohammad Imran and thank you for quick answer. I've just tried your method and runned it on my virtual machine and I still get the mac address from the virtual machine and not from my psychical machine.

Comment: @DervisAvdic it's very difficult to get what you are looking for in VmWare. but You can do one thing. Write a WCF service which contain WMI service Contract and Host it on your Physical Machine. so you can call this WCF service from you License service and our WCF service will return you information of physical machine.